# How can I get top 3 value with selection of combobox in C# from database

Tags: c#, sql, database, data-files

I want to select combobox items and want to show top 3 possibilities on datagridview according to my selections in c# 2010 express. I created database using C#.

```
    private void add_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
        sqlcon.ConnectionString = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=D:\Mystudies\C#\SQL Database\MakerSelectionDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True";

        // insert Logic
        sqlcon.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from makerinfo Where [Equipment Type] = '" + equipmenttype_combobox.Text.Trim() + "' and Plant='" + plant_combobox.Text.Trim() + "'", sqlcon);

        // I could not combine this code to combobox selection.
        // SqlDataAdapter eval = new SqlDataAdapter("select top 3 safety from makerinfo order by Safety desc", sqlcon);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter db = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        datagridview.DataSource = dt;

        sqlcon.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why not use use `Select top ૩` and `order by Saftey Desc` in your query

Comment: Thx for your reply. Do you have any sample link or document ? I do not know how can I run with SQL query combined with interface.

Comment: `SqlDataAdapter("select top ૩ safety from makerinfo Where [Equipment Type] = '" + equipmenttype_combobox.Text.Trim() + "' and Plant='" + plant_combobox.Text.Trim() + "' order by Saftey desc", sqlcon);` did you try this?

Comment: It is done :) Thanks you very much. Now I will try to get all row information.